# Restricting Web Application usage when Licensing

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, web-applications

I am just putting some finishing touches onto a Licensing solution for a Web Application I have created for SharePoint. I want to be able prevent the page from loading the Web Application Content when the license is invalid. I have tried the following...

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (LicensingInformation.Status == Status.Active)
        {
           base.Render(writer);
        }
    }
```

but it kills everything on the page, I still want to view the master page and a jquery dialog box I have created to display feedback to the user.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Much Appreciated

Phill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions?

- Redirect to a "invalid license page"
- Set the `Visible` property of some `Panel` control for the content you want to hide
- Disable rendering of your control instead of the rendering of the page
- ...